# How to sum 2 columns and display in 3rd one in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

How can we sum two columns and get the result in third column in Tableau ?

I tried doing that but instead of getting as in column header I got in row!
If someone can help! Thanks !

### A | B

2 | 3

3 | 2

---

### A | B | C

2 | 3 | 5

3 | 2 | 5

Answer (score 1):

You can use the row grand totals which is available in the Analysis menu. It will sum up your rows and show in a separate column.

You can also create a calculated field and put the three columns in the Measure Values card. They will appear side by side

Comment: That adds the entire rows !Suppose , I have 6 columns and I have to just add 2 columns and give the result in the new computed column .

Comment: Edited answer to cover the scenario