# How I can add three columns values and return values in new column tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACkyK.png)

example: 10+20+25 = 55(in new column)

Comment: Please see response to similar query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53400884/how-to-sum-2-columns-and-display-in-3rd-one-in-tableau/53402778?noredirect=1#comment93689045_53402778

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values you would like to add up are all from the same measure you can add them all by selecting 'Show Row Grand Total' from the Analysis option in the toolbar.

[image]

This works when the values you would like to add share the same row. Of course, you can also show the Grand Total and the bottom of the column if that's the way your values are oriented as well.

Here's an example of what this looks like in a similar situation to your example.

[image]

Hope that helps!